# C program created many proccesses, crash the OS and stuffed 40GB into log directory

Tags: apt, kernel, disk-usage, log, c

I create the following program which needs to "play ping pong" between a parent process and its child process.

Even while working on it, while compiling, I noticed that my PC starts to work harder and harder but I didn't really think it's a problem.

In the end I found myself crashing my Linux, creating lots of different processes that slow down the PC and also create a lot temp/logs file and cause my disk to have 200MB of free space instead of 35GB .

How can I fix those problems?

1. How can I stop my program from creating a lot of different processes?
2. How can I clean up my logs directory? I tried
   `sudo apt autoremove` and `autoclean` and delete all `.gz` files in the `/var/log` directory.

But it did not help. My disk space still stands on free 200MB and a `/var/log` directory of almost 40GB for some reason.

I don't want to remove necessary files that located in the `/var/log` directory so I'm not removing the entire directory.

Why did my program even created so many temp or logs file?

Thanks.

```
is_parent_turn = 1;

void handle_siguser1(int signum);
void handle_siguser1(int signum);

int main()
{
    /*  create a child process  */
    pid_t pid = fork();
    
    if (pid < 0)
        exit(1);
    
    signal(SIGUSR1, handle_siguser1);
    signal(SIGUSR2, handle_siguser2);
    
    /*  returned to the newly created child process. */
    if (0 == pid)
    {   
        while (1)
        {
            /*  pause child process and let parent to begin */
            sleep(2);
            
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
            
        }
    }
        
    /* returned to parent */
    else
    {   
        while (1)
        {
            kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
        }
    }
        
    return 0;   
}
/******************************************************************************/
void handle_siguser1(int signum)
{
    if (is_parent_turn)
    {
        printf("\n\nPING\n\n");
        is_parent_turn = 0;
    }
    
    else
    {
        sleep(2);
    }
}
/******************************************************************************/
void handle_siguser2(int signum)
{
    if (!is_parent_turn)
    {
        printf("\n\nPONG\n\n");
        is_parent_turn = 1;
    }
    
    else
    {
        sleep(2);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to ask this question on StackOverflow, which is a development-centric site 

Comment: @matigo the major question here is "how should I clean up the `var/log` directory and remove all the files the were created by my program and take up more than 35GB without removing the really important system files

Comment: You can use the terminal or Nautilus get into the `/var/log/` directory and, from there, delete the large files. So long as you’re not removing directories or changing permissions, you’ll be fine …

Comment: file called `syslog` is 22GB

Comment: and what are some of the entries in `/var/log/syslog`? The entries should help you debug your program.

Comment: Your c program seems incomplete, and does not compile as listed. I have made it compile, and it doesn't make any entries in `/var/log/syslog`, but it doesn't loop forever or terminate. It does print "PING" then "PONG" once. You should kill your stuff `killall a.out`